# making a plot with error bars and without error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data:

```
structure(list(location = "Nepal", govt_mohp_bites = 85483, dogs_govt_mohp_bites = 75562, 
    other_animals_govt_mohp_bites = 9921, true_cases_number = c(p = 1085610), 
    true_cases_number_conf_low = 964987, true_cases_number_conf_high = 1206233, 
    dogs_true_cases_number = c(p = 896010), dogs_true_cases_number_conf_low = 796454, 
    dogs_true_cases_number_conf_high = 995567, other_animals_true_cases_number = c(p = 189599), 
    other_animals_true_cases_number_conf_low = 168533, other_animals_true_cases_number_conf_high = 210666, 
    only_bites_true_cases_number = c(p = 899059), only_bites_true_cases_number_conf_low = 799163, 
    only_bites_true_cases_number_conf_high = 998954, only_bites_dogs_true_cases_number = c(p = 742040), 
    only_bites_dogs_true_cases_number_conf_low = 659591, only_bites_dogs_true_cases_number_conf_high = 824489, 
    only_bites_other_animals_true_cases_number = c(p = 157019), 
    only_bites_other_animals_true_cases_number_conf_low = 139572, 
    only_bites_other_animals_true_cases_number_conf_high = 174465, 
    overall_underreporting_rate = c(p = 92.1258090628158), overall_underreporting_rate_conf_low = 91.1415351956678, 
    overall_underreporting_rate_conf_high = 92.9132281565342, 
    dogs_underreporting_rate = c(p = 91.5668395494997), dogs_underreporting_rate_conf_low = 90.5126944931872, 
    dogs_underreporting_rate_conf_high = 92.4101555945498, other_animals_underreporting_rate = c(p = 94.7673911905283), 
    other_animals_underreporting_rate_conf_low = 94.1133150893443, 
    other_animals_underreporting_rate_conf_high = 95.2906520714754, 
    only_bites_overall_underreporting_rate = c(p = 90.4919448691265), 
    only_bites_overall_underreporting_rate_conf_low = 89.3034379777674, 
    only_bites_overall_underreporting_rate_conf_high = 91.4427503822139, 
    only_bites_dogs_underreporting_rate = c(p = 89.8169913416486), 
    only_bites_dogs_underreporting_rate_conf_low = 88.5441152593547, 
    only_bites_dogs_underreporting_rate_conf_high = 90.8352922074838, 
    only_bites_other_animals_underreporting_rate = c(p = 93.6816450812986), 
    only_bites_other_animals_underreporting_rate_conf_low = 92.8918507164609, 
    only_bites_other_animals_underreporting_rate_conf_high = 94.3134805731687), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to make a bar graph where I am comparing the "govt_mohp_bites" with the "true_cases_number" where "true_cases_number_conf_low" and "true_cases_number_conf_high" are the CI of the error bars. how do I make a graph where one graph doesn't have error bars but another has error bars?

Will making a table like the following help?

[image: maybe this type of table will help?]

Comment: https://r-graph-gallery.com/ is a great source for finding the visual effects of a plot and seeing the data/code used to make it. If that doesn't help, please try something, then post your code so we can work with what you've started.